# Logging query string with express-bunyan-logger and graphql

Tags: express, graphql-js, bunyan

I've made a [short, self contained example](https://github.com/pcsanwald/tmp) of a problem I'm having with express-bunyan-logger.

I'm trying to add [express-bunyan-logger](https://github.com/villadora/express-bunyan-logger) as middleware, and utilize `includesFn` to log the query string and body as a custom fields.

```
const app = express();

const graphqlLogger = require('express-bunyan-logger')({
  name: 'graphql-logger',
  includesFn: (req, res) => {
    const includes = {};
    if (req.body) includes.req_body = JSON.stringify(req.body);
    if (req.query) includes.req_query = JSON.stringify(req.query);
    return includes;
  },
});

app.use(graphqlLogger);
```

Problem is, even for a URL of the form http://localhost:4000/graphql?query=query%20%7B%0A%20%20books%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20title%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D, the `req_query` and `req_body` fields are always empty. If I inspect the `req` object that's passed to `includesFn` in a debugger, it doesn't contain any values for req.query or req.params.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here; how do I get the `includesFn` to log the query string and body correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, turns out the `includesFn` is being called twice, once per each request.

First, for the `GET` request, then you will get only the `req.query` object not empty.

The second request is the `POST` request that is being with `JSON` data, so in order to to get the `req.body` defined and not empty, you have to do the following:

1. run `npm install body-parser`.
2. include the following in your `app.js` file:

   ```
   const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

   ...

   app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
     extended: true
   }));

   app.use(bodyParser.json());
   ```